# Globally (in SE network) setting an avatar

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, gravatar

I have had a couple of almost inactive accounts on the SE network; I have always used my SE login to access them. Recently I've actually started using them and would thus like to set a non-default avatar. I only seem to be able to this in a site-based manner; my actual SE user page doesn't give me the options to do so.

Am I doing it wrong or is it just not possible at the time?

Comment: @Ben Simultaneous edits FTW!

Comment: I was just typing that comment @Yannis! I'm more proud of the fact that we both added the same tag :-).

Comment: I assume this means this is the right forum for this question? (even if I stupidly forgot the tag, thanks for having my back guys :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct @MHaaZ. For historical reasons meta.stackoverflow.com _is_ meta.stackexchange.com (hence the redirect). There's plans to split them at some point it just hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Go to your profile page in one of the sites. Click "edit". Click "change picture" and choose the new picture to be your avatar. Now the magic is to click the big "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" button in the bottom. (Not 100% it's working and don't want to sacrifice my Meta details so let me know if it works) :)